# Redux data.map is not a function (intento de normalizar datos en actions )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Soy nuevo en redux, no tengo idea de cómo solucionarlo, llevo gran parte de la noche en esto :(

Json Server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que llevo por ahora con mi actions,

```js
export const bringData = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOADER,
  });
  try {
    const respuesta = await axios.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api');
    const prueba = {};
    respuesta.data.map(
      ( total) =>
        (prueba[total.confirmed] = {
          ...prueba[total.confirmed],
        })
    );
    dispatch({
      type: BRING_ALL,
      payload: prueba,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR,
      payload: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

cuando todo compilo el codigo redux me arroja:

```
payload:"respuesta.data.map is not a function"
```

Los reducers,

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  dataCovid: [],
  dataUser: [],
  loader: false,
  error: '',
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BRING_ALL:
      return { ...state, dataCovid: action.payload, loader: false };
    case USER_DATA:
      return { ...state, dataUser: action.payload, loader: false };
    case LOADER:
      return { ...state, loader: true };
    case ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Lo que ando intenado es consultar datos de casos confirmado de la api

la api: https://covid19.mathdro.id/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de ver la respuesta de la api que usas esta no devuelve un array y no entiendo porque haces el `map`.

El método `map` es para arrays y en tu caso la respuesta que te devuelve la api es un objeto con las propiedades `confirmed, recovered`, etc. Por eso te da el error.

Esto el que te devuelve la api.

```
{
  "confirmed": {
    "value": 2494915,
    "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
  },
  "recovered": {
    "value": 658009,
    "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/recovered"
  },
  "deaths": {
    "value": 171249,
    "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/deaths"
  },
  "dailySummary": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily",
  "dailyTimeSeries": {
    "pattern": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/[dateString]",
    "example": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/2-14-2020"
  },
  "image": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/og",
  "source": "https://github.com/mathdroid/covid19",
  "countries": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries",
  "countryDetail": {
    "pattern": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/[country]",
    "example": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/USA"
  },
  "lastUpdate": "2020-04-21T10:38:47.000Z"
}
```

si quieres guardar todos estos datos en store solo tienes que pasar el `respuesta.data` al dispatch y ya lo tendras en el store.

```
export const bringData = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOADER,
  });
  try {
    const respuesta = await axios.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api');

    dispatch({
      type: BRING_ALL,
      payload: respuesta.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR,
      payload: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: hhahaha, culpa mia, un error estupido, creo que fue por falta de dormir thanks...